# Mysql 8: Host is blocked because of many connections errors - how to find out what the error is?

Tags: mysql-8.0

We see the mysql "Host is blocked because of many connections errors" error, which is weird because we have exactly one app that connects to it, and which always connects exactly the same way with the same credentials.

does mysql log anywhere what the error is?